# Move a locked resource to locked destination in WebDAV

Tags: http-headers, webdav

With move command, i already can do this action:

- Move a normal resource to a normal destination
- Move a locked resource to a normal destination
- Move a normal resource to a locked destination

But when I try to move a locked resource to a locked destination, I always get error code 424.

Here the request:

```
MOVE /pub1/test_data.txt HTTP/1.1
Host: www.myhost.com
Destination: https://www.myhost.com/pub3/test_data.txt
Overwrite: T
If: <https://www.myhost.com/pub1/test_data.txt>(<opaquelocktoken:19e4880c-0fce-477d-8e07-ca13ffe328eb>)<https://www.myhost.com/pub3/test_data.txt>(<opaquelocktoken:5f29e527-7577-4036-a5dc-fb9f83f8434d>)
```

The first token is lock token of file test_data.txt, the second is lock token of pub3 folder. I try another If header look like:

```
If: (<opaquelocktoken:19e4880c-0fce-477d-8e07-ca13ffe328eb>)(<opaquelocktoken:5f29e527-7577-4036-a5dc-fb9f83f8434d>)
```

but it also doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<D:multistatus>
 <D:response>
<D:href>/pub1</D:href>
<D:status>HTTP/1.1 412 Precondition Failed</D:status>
<D:responsedescription>A validation error has occurred on the parent resource, preventing the operation on the resource specified by the Request-URI. The error was: The precondition(s) specified by the "If:" header did not match this resource. At least one failure is because: a State-token was supplied, but it was not found in the locks on this resource.</D:responsedescription>
 </D:response>
</D:multistatus>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the If header field, try to use the *folder*'s URI instead:

```
If: <https://www.myhost.com/pub1/test_data.txt>(<opaquelocktoken:19e4880c-0fce-477d-8e07-ca13ffe328eb>)<https://www.myhost.com/pub3/>(<opaquelocktoken:5f29e527-7577-4036-a5dc-fb9f83f8434d>)
```